# Square Connect API - running composer in the directory

Tags: php, composer-php

Okay I am going off the GIthub documentation for the Square Connect API which is below:

[Square Connect API](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk#installing)

And I'm confused with where it mentions you need to run composer.

I run the command in command prompt but get an error message:

> $ php composer.phar require square/connect
>   '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I must admit I am very new to using composer and I'm not even entirely sure of what it's used for, so if you have an answer if you could explain or link to that I would appreciate it.

Furthermore, is composer only able to run on a localhost? Because below this explanation it says "from Github" and instructs to download and open in project folder. I am assuming then that if it's not on a development site or localhost, you do not use Composer.

I have been looking around for a clear explanation to this but all anyone really does is link back to the Composer website which to me is a little unclear.

Any explanations?

Comment: Leave the `$` off. That indicates a command line prompt. Just run `php composer.phar install`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems. when you install it requires you to pick a command line.  By default for me, it was php.exe (wherever you have that saved).

I found it and added it as a path to my windows command prompt (pretty easy to find the youtube video on this), and then you must first start by simply typing the word 'composer' into the command prompt to run in; then continue as directed on the square site.

If you get another error that says it can't open file: `composer.phar`, then rewrite the line without '.phar'.